Custom Date Format in Flutter CupertinoDatePicker?
I'm using Flutter's CupertinoDatePicker to pick a date, but I want to use a custom date format as Monday, April 10, 2024. However, I can't find a way to change the format. While CupertinoDatePicker has options to set mode and dateOrder, but they do not meet the requirements.
The expected date format I want to display in the date picker UI is Monday, April 10, 2024, and I do not want to format it after picking the date

you want to show the date in the date picker in this format? or want to format the date after it has been picked from the date picker?

I want to display a custom date format in the date picker UI, not after it has been picked. I have updated the question to reflect this for more clarity.

@RoyKrueger I think customizable_datetime_picker not return Day

You can use intl package to achieve that.
String getFormattedDate(DateTime dateTime) {
    return DateFormat('EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy').format(dateTime);
  }

Pass your selected date which you get from onDateTimeChanged
Edit:
If you want to show this format in the UI then you should consider creating your custom picker.
class CustomDatePickerDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final DateTime initialDate;

  const CustomDatePickerDialog({required this.initialDate, super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomDatePickerDialog> createState() => _CustomDatePickerDialogState();
}

class _CustomDatePickerDialogState extends State<CustomDatePickerDialog> {
  late DateTime selectedDate;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedDate = widget.initialDate;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Text(
              DateFormat('EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy').format(selectedDate),
            ),
          ),
          CalendarDatePicker(
            initialDate: selectedDate,
            firstDate: DateTime(2000),
            lastDate: DateTime(2101),
            onDateChanged: (DateTime date) {
              setState(() {
                selectedDate = date;
              });
            },
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(selectedDate);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Then call it like this:
 final DateTime? picked =
         await showDialog<DateTime>(
         context: context,
         builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return CustomDatePickerDialog(
                     initialDate: selectedDate);
         },
      );

   if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
          setState(() {
            selectedDate = picked;
          });
         }
       


He needs to show the date in this format in the DatePicker dialog.

I tried using customizable_datetime_picker with the date format EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy, but it's giving a null check error. However, it works with other date format such as dd-MM-yyyy.
